# fetch out the frequency of numeric values

Tags: r

I want to create a function which can detect the frequency of numeric values in all columns excepting columns have "Text".

Only integer values should be numeric , rest all should be considered as char for ex.(21%) . NA's can be excluded as blank.

```
library(tidyverse)
    df <-  tibble(Region = c("AU","USA",65,"USA","!UK",88,"USA","CA","!UK"),
                  lock = c(26,18,NA,1,"Test",15,NA,"21%",13),
                  type= c("sale",NA,NA,"target","target",NA,"sale",NA,"target"),
                  state_Text=c("TX","CA","NY","OT","DE","WN","WA","PH","NJ"))
```

Comment: R can't mix numeric and character values in the same vector. The numeric values will be coerced to character values. If you run `sapply(df, class)` you will see everything is a character. Are you considering the value "21%" numeric? Because the percent sign mucks things up for `as.numeric("21%")`. So what exactly do you define as "numeric"? Is it something that only has digits? And you want NA values in the denominator? And are you counting NA as numeric? Because otherwise I'm not sure why type has such a high percentage since those seem all non-numeric. Why isn't "Region" in the output?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are getting 71% from `df$type`?

Comment: When you respond to MrFlick's requests for clarification you should use SO's facilities to [edit] your question body. Do NOT use comments. And while you are at it you should properly capitalize your English sentences and the first person pronoun.

Comment: I have updated the question, so in lock column we have 5 numeric values and total we have 7 values . so 5 divided by seven is 71 % of numeric values

Comment: so in my original data frame column definition already provided as character to all column now i wanted to check the frequency of numeric values every column columns have .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a helper function to determine the proportion of values that only contain digits.

```
num_perc <- function(x) mean(grepl("^\\d+$", x), na.rm=TRUE)
```

We can then use it with `dplyr` to calculate the value for all columns that do not end with "_Text

```
df %>% summarise(across(!ends_with("_Text"), num_perc))
#   Region  lock  type
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  0.222 0.556     0
```

If you really want one row per column, then you can also pivot using `tidyr`

```
df %>% 
  summarise(across(!ends_with("_Text"), num_perc)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything())
#   name   value
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Region 0.222
# 2 lock   0.556
# 3 type   0
```